# Why Authorize Identity not work correctly?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, asp.net-identity, user-roles

Hi I try Create project with asp.net core mvc. I Create some Controller and also user Identity 3.1 for add manage users and add role to them. I Create 2 role (Normal, Admin) and for example I want only normal user access to the My AccountController. also the users default role is Normal after Registered. But when this type of user login and try open the account they redirect to the signin page. How can I fix this ?
i change all of the password option false temporary to create user test faster.
the below code is all of my configure from startup.

```
 [Authorize(Roles = "Normal")]

public class AccountController : Controller
{
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View("Account");
    }
}
```

---

```
enter code| services.AddDbContext<DataAcessLayer.DB>(s => s.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("CON1")) );
        services.AddIdentity<User, IdentityRole>(option =>
        {
            option.Password.RequireDigit = false;
            option.Password.RequireLowercase = false;
            option.Password.RequireUppercase = false;
            option.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
            option.Password.RequiredLength = 5;
            option.SignIn.RequireConfirmedPhoneNumber = false;
            option.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = false;
            option.SignIn.RequireConfirmedEmail = false;
        })
            
            .AddUserManager<UserManager<User>>()
            .AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
            .AddRoleManager<RoleManager<IdentityRole>>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<DataAcessLayer.DB>();
             



        services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
        {
            options.AccessDeniedPath = "/Sign/404";
            options.Cookie.Name = "WebAppIdentityCookie";
            options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
            options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(20);
            options.LoginPath = "/Sign/SignIn";
            options.SlidingExpiration = true;
           
        });
```

and this is my login code:

```
 [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> login(Models.UserModel usermodel)
    {
        var user = await userManager.FindByNameAsync(usermodel.UserName);
        if (user == null)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "نام کاربری یا رمز عبور اشتباه است.");
            return View("SignIn", usermodel);
        }

        var SignInResult = await signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(user, usermodel.Password, true, true);

        if (SignInResult.Succeeded)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Account");
        }
        else
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "نام کاربری یا رمز عبور اشتباه است.");
            return View("SignIn", usermodel);
        }

    }
```

---

```
       public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
            app.UseHsts();
        }
        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseRouting();


        app.UseAuthorization();
        app.UseAuthentication();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
    }
```

Comment: Put the complete codes of the login and identity configuration

Comment: ok. i edit and write my startup config too.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be a problem so far. Put the pipeline codes (middlewares) as well

Comment: I edit and add this part too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try changing

```
app.UseAuthorization();
app.UseAuthentication();
```

to

```
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization()
```

read this article:
[Asp.net Core Middlewares](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?view=aspnetcore-6.0)

Comment: I try it and worked perfectly now. thank you. but I still have question all of the tutorial video and article i read so far said we should use the UseAuthorization first. however thank you again also for the article you shared.

Comment: No, if it is stated that way somewhere, it is completely wrong, to make it easier to understand, `authentication` means `who are you?` In fact, the permission to enter, but `authorization` checks the level of access, like saying `where do you want to go?`